# Wrong model item passed to view is of type 'x', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'y'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am learning form https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-aspnet-mvc-5-course/ and I don't understand what is wrong with my code. I pass `ByCustomerIdViewModel` to view but it requires `RandomMovieViewModel`.

error screenshot:
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ognHz.png)

Here is my code

You can also check the whole code on my [GitHub](https://github.com/koksztul/Vidly) project:

**CustomerController**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Vidly.Models;
using Vidly.ModelsView;
namespace Vidly.Controllers
{
    public class CustomersController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Customers
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
                var customers = new List<Customer>
                 {
                    new Customer { Id = 1, Name= "Koksztul"},
                    new Customer { Id = 2, Name= "Januszek"}
                 };

                var viewModel = new ByCustomerIdViewModel
                {
                    Customers1 = customers
                };
                return View(viewModel);
        }

        [Route("customers/details/{id}")]
        public ActionResult ByCustomerId(int id)
        {
            var customers = new List<Customer>
                 {
                    new Customer { Id = 1, Name= "Koksztul"},
                    new Customer { Id = 2, Name= "Januszek"}
                 };

            var viewModel = new ByCustomerIdViewModel
            {
                customerId = id,
                Customers1 = customers
            };
            return View(viewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomerModel**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Vidly.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ByCustomerIdModelView**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Vidly.Models;

namespace Vidly.ModelsView
{
    public class ByCustomerIdViewModel
    {
        public int customerId { get; set; }
        public List<Customer> Customers1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model Vidly.ModelsView.ByCustomerIdViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


@foreach (var customer in Model.Customers1)
{
<li> @Html.ActionLink(customer.Name, "details", "customers", new { id = customer.Id},
                null  
                )</li>

}
```

Comment: Are you intending for both action methods to return the same View? Unless you specify otherwise, your action methods will look for a view with the same name, so your Index action method will look for a view called Index. There's ways to override that if that's what you want.

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you add a screenshot or something?

Comment: Welcome to SO. From the code you have included I can't get what's the problem. Are you facing a compilation problem ? If so, please specify exactly at which point and add also the error message. For instance, both Views defined in Views/Customers takes as a model `Vidly.ModelsView.ByCustomerIdViewModel`. Furthermore, from the Controller you have shared, it seems that you provide this. So I don't get what's the problem. Thanks

Comment: You might just need to rebuild your project or something.

Comment: @GidiBloke screenshot https://imgur.com/a/HwTLm7L

Comment: @Christos error screenshot https://imgur.com/a/HwTLm7L

Comment: There is also another view called random if u check github. The view was doing the same way and it works.

Comment: @mason The problem is the index view requies another model thais i pass to him. I attach screenshot above. There is another view called Random if u check code on my github. I was fallowing the tutorial and did it. Next i wanted to make my own view. Same way like the random view, but i got the error about pass wrong model.

Comment: @bolkay i did it many times. Im trying to solve this from fre hours.

Comment: @Koksztul please check this https://dotnetfiddle.net/hi9uRA. As it seems one of your scenarios is working. Isn't that correct ?